# Update multiple registers in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql table with these values

```
name      |      parent  |     owner
--------------------------------
Lv1       |      Lv1     |     Lv1
Lv2       |      Lv1     |     Lv1
Lv3       |      Lv2     |     Lv1
Lv2-1     |      Lv1     |    Lv1
```

I need update all registers with the same text

Example: if update is lv1 to lv1-1 the table result is

```
name      |      parent   |    owner
====================================
lv1-1     |      lv1-1    |     lv1-1
Lv2       |      lv1-1    |     lv1-1
Lv3       |      Lv2      |     lv1-1
Lv2-1     |      lv1-1    |     lv1-1
====================================
```

How can I write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
declare @oldValue NVARCHAR(10)
set @oldValue = 'lv1'

update table
set
   name = case when name = @oldValue then @oldValue + '-1' else name end,
   parent = case when parent = @oldValue then @oldValue + '-1' else parent end,
   owner = case when owner = @oldValue then @oldValue + '-1' else owner end
```

This updates (on all rows of the table) the value in every column to `lv1-1` if it before was `lv1`. Otherwise it keeps the old value.